# Caching JMS Session with CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, session, jms

I learned that CachingConnectionFactory has the ability to cache JMS session. However, I don't understand how can I retrieve the cached Session programmingly.

My Spring configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <construction-arg index="0" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="50" />
</bean>
```

where `connectionFactory` is the connection factory created by JNDI.

The way I create session is that:

```
QueueConnection connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.DUP_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

However, it looks like the session created by createQueueSession is always a new session rather than cached ones. It takes about 1.5 milliseconds to create a session, which doesn't sound retrieved a cached one.

Can someone please let me know how can I get the session cache working?

Comment: 1.5ms? And you are worrying about that?

Comment: Yes. The system I am working on is a high concurrency system. Every microseconds counts. And this also proves it is not retrieving a cached session.

Comment: Enable trace logging for `org.springframework.jms` and see what is in the logging if it does or does not retrieve a cached session.